# SQL count totals for each number in a range (Edit: via a UDF)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, select, amazon-redshift

I have data similar to the following in Amazon (AWS) RedShift which represents various people's reading logs and each row is a record of the span of chapters read on a particular day:

```
| person | date   | book     | chapter_start | chapter_end |
|--------|--------|----------|---------------|-------------|
| Alice  | 7/1/15 | Big Red  | 4             | 7           |
| Bob    | 7/1/15 | Big Red  | 1             | 5           |
| James  | 7/1/15 | Big Red  | 2             | 9           |
| Tim    | 7/1/15 | Big Red  | 10            | 12          |
| Alice  | 7/2/15 | Big Red  | 8             | 10          |
| Bob    | 7/2/15 | Big Red  | 6             | 8           |
| James  | 7/2/15 | Big Red  | 10            | 11          |
| Tim    | 7/1/15 | Blue Sky | 1             | 3           |
| Alice  | 7/1/15 | Blue Sky | 3             | 4           |
```

I am wondering if there is a SQL query (remember it needs to be RedShift compatible postgresql) that can produce a count for each chapter in the span such that the results would like the following:

```
| book     | chapter | count |
|----------|---------|-------|
| Big Red  | 1       | 1     |
| Big Red  | 2       | 2     |
| Big Red  | 3       | 2     |
| Big Red  | 4       | 3     |
| Big Red  | 5       | 3     |
| Big Red  | 6       | 3     |
| Big Red  | 7       | 3     |
| Big Red  | 8       | 3     |
| Big Red  | 9       | 2     |
| Big Red  | 10      | 3     |
| Big Red  | 11      | 2     |
| Big Red  | 12      | 1     |
| Blue Sky | 1       | 1     |
| Blue Sky | 2       | 1     |
| Blue Sky | 3       | 2     |
| Blue Sky | 4       | 2     |
```

Note in the results above, the count is NOT simply accounting for chapter_start and chapter_end. For example, if we processed the entry where Tim read Blue Sky from chapter 1 to 3, chapters 1, **2** and 3 of Blue Sky should have had their individual counters incremented.

**Edit (July 28 2015):** Upon further research, it appears that while Mureinik's suggestion below would work for a fully postgresql compliant system, RedShift only supports a small subset of the postgresql functions (see: [Unsupported PostgeSQL Functions in RedShift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html)) therefore his answer does not work on RedShift. For the time being, it appears that this would not be possible via User Defined Functions (UDFs) either as they are not support yet either. One point of encouragement, the RedShift product manager confirmed that they are planning to support postgresql compliant UDFs by September 2015. << fingers crossed >>

With the above said, is anyone willing to take take on the equivalent of GENERATE_SERIES() via a UDF?

**Edit (Sept 11 2015):** UDF's are finally available in RedShift. See the newly released [AWS RedShift UDF documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html). Clarifying the need--what is needed is a set returning function in python that replicates the functionality of the [Postgres GENERATE_SERIES() function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html). Is anyone up for the challenge?

**Edit (Jan 08 2016):** After some back and forth with AWS and some clarification of their documentation the UDF's that are supported in RedShift appear to only be capable of returning single values, not a set. Therefore, at this time, it does not seem possible to create a UDF that would mimic this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-srf.html) to create a list of all the chapters between `chapter_start` and `chapter_end`, and then just group by them and count:

```
SELECT   book, chapter, COUNT(*)
FROM     (SELECT book, GENERATE_SERIES(chapter_start, chapter_end) AS chapter
          FROM   mytable) t
GROUP BY book, chapter
```

Comment: Mureinik, your solution works well in postresql but it fails when executed on a RedShift cluster with the error: "Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables". This was quite the letdown because the simple test of SELECT * FROM generate_series(2,4); which did execute correctly on my RedShift cluster.  Turns out GENERATE_SERIES() is on the unsupported functions list for RedShift (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html). Any other suggestions?